# How to write down slap bass on score?

Tags: notation, bass-guitar

How could I write down slap bass (slap and pop) on sheet music?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard way to do notate slaps and pops is to use a letter above or below the note to specify the technique and a standard or "x" note head to specify whether the note is sounded or muted.

Different sources adhere to different standards regarding the letters used to indicate slap, but it's usally "S" or "T". Pops are indicated by "P". There is typically a legend that explains the notation.

For example:

- the website [Ultimate Guitar](https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/en/wiki/Slapping_and_popping#Tablature%20notation) uses `S` for "slap" and `P` for "pop"
- the publisher [Hal Leonard](https://www.halleonard.com/bin/musicNotationBass.pdf) uses `T` ("thumb") for "slap" and `P` for "pop"
- [Berklee Online](https://online.berklee.edu/takenote/slap-bass-lines-slap-technique/) also uses `T` and `P` for "slap" and "pop" ("pull"), respectively.

So a simple slap/pop bass figure might look something like:

[image: Example notation]

The above example would mean to

1. Slap the open E string, and let it ring
2. Slap and mute the open E string
3. Pop the 7th fret D on the G string

Comment: AFAIK Guitar Pro also uses S "slap" and P "pop" notation ("T" for tapping - not for slap bass)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen an "X" note head. Once I saw "snap" written (like pizz or arco).

This page has a bit more.
https://www.artofslapbass.com/adam-booker-slap-bass-notation/

Comment: doesnt the X indicate _left or right hand mute_ of a slap or pop?